# Pass variable to multiple templates in pybottle

Tags: python, bottle

We have a function in controller.py:

```
@bottle.get("/")
def start():
    username = check_login()
    l = artifacts.get_entries(100)
    return bottle.template('streams_template', 
        dict(myentries=l, username=username))
```

streams_template.tpl

```
% include menu.tpl
```

menu.tpl

```
<a class="menu" href="/cart/{{username}}"><div class="menulist">Your Cart</div></a>
```

This will generate: NameError: name 'username' is not defined

How should I pass {{username}} to the menu.tpl?

Comment: Sorry all. It was easy enough. Just needed to pass the variable in the include like this:
% include menu username=username